# Predefine entity values on creation

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have the following model classes that are related by a one-to-many relationship. The classes are persisted into a SQL Server database via the Code First approach:

```
public class Topic
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Topic")]
    public virtual IList<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }

    //some other properties...
}

public class Chapter : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Key { get; set }

    public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }

    //some other properties...
}
```

Each `Topic` contains a bunch of `Chapters`. Each `Chapter` has a `Key` that must be unique within its `Topic`.

I was trying to validate this with the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{  
    var chaptersWithSameKey = Topic.Chapters.Where(t => t.Key == Key);
    foreach (var item in chaptersWithSameKey)
    {
        if (item.Id != Id)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("The key must be unique.", new string[] { "Key" });
            break;
        }
    }            
}
```

However, `Topic` is always `null` when validation occurs after posting to the Create or Edit action. This seems reasonable because the views contain no information about the `Topic`. However, I can extract the topic in the controller because the topic's id is part of the URL.

My first attempt was to set the topic right at the beginning of the Post Create action in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int topicId, Chapter chapter)
{
    var topic = db.Topics.Find(topicId);
    if (topic == null)
        return HttpNotFound();
    chapter.Topic = topic;
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
        ...
}
```

However, the chapter's `Validate` method is called before the controller can do anything. Therefore, the chapter's topic is again `null`.

Another approach was to tell the Create view what topic it belongs to by:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int topicId)
{
    var topic = ...
    var newChapter = new Chapter() { Topic = topic };
    return View(newChapter);
}
```

and set up a hidden field in the view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Topic)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Topic.Id)
```

The first one gives a `null` topic as before. This seems natural because the rendered hidden field's value is just the topic's `ToString()` result.

The second one seemingly tries to validate the topic, but fails because there are missing properties. The actual reason is a `NullReferenceException` when a read-only property of `Topic` tries to evaluate another `null` property. I have no clue why the read-only property is accessed at all. The call stack has some `Validate...` methods.

So what is the best solution for the above scenario? I'm trying to do validation in the model, but some necessary values are missing which could be retrieved in a controller.

I could create a view model for this task that contains a `int TopicId` instead of the `Topic Topic`. But then I would have to copy every property and annotation to the view model or do it via inheritance. The first approach seems quite inefficient.

So up to now the inheritance method is probably the best option. But are there any other options which do not come with the need to introduce an additional type?

Comment: If `Topic` is null why isn't a `NullReferenceException` being thrown at `Topic.Chapters.Where`?

Comment: @haim770 Yes, of course. I thought that was obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to realize that Validation (then your `Validate()` method) is performed early by the `ModelBinder`, before your Action executes.

Second, I would argue that your main problem is that you aren't using a `ViewModel` but rather return your `Entity/Model` to the View and back to the Controller.

Your Views usually have different responsibilities and concerns than the Models/Entities themselves (just like in your case). different data structure, different validation rules and most importantly, you could shape your ViewModel object to accommodate the exact Page/View needs.

Your current `Validate()` method is seem to suit the Data-Layer validation needs, not your Views validation needs.

Try this:

```
public class CreateChapterViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  // possible not needed for 'Create' flow
    public string Key { get; set }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {  
         // validation logic that applies to Chapter creation only, for example:
         // if (this.Key == null) ...
    }
}
```

Then in your `Action`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int topicId, CreateChapterViewModel chapter)
{
     ...
}
```

To summarize, don't try to force your Entities on your Views, they usually have different needs, feed them with ViewModels and let them send ViewModels as well.

The trade-off with this approach is that you'll have to map your Entities to ViewModels and  back, either create your own Mappers or use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution which is a slight adaption of haim's answer. The reason why I don't agree with him completely is that I want to enforce model layer constraints when creating (or editing) an entity. The mentioned constraint (unique key) is a model layer constraint and I don't see why it should be moved to the view.

I did the following. The `Chapter` remained untouched (including validation attributes and the custom validation method). I created a view model that inherits the `Chapter's` properties and behavior and adds the `TopicId` property that is used to identify the topic. Furthermore, it overrides the `Topic` property and fetches the topic from the database.

```
[NotMapped]
public class ChapterViewModel : Chapter
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public override Topic Topic
    {
        get
        {
            return DbContext.Topics.Find(TopicId);
        }
    }

    private MyDbContext ctx;
    public MyDbContext DbContext
    {
        private get { if (ctx == null) ctx = new CadenzaDbContext(); return ctx; }
        set { ctx = value; }
    }

    public ChapterViewModel() { }
    public ChapterViewModel(Chapter c)
    {
        Id = c.Id;
        TopicId = c.Topic == null ? -1 : c.Topic.Id;
        Key = c.Key;
    }
    public Chapter ToPlainChapter(MyDbContext db)
    {
        DbContext = db;
        return new Chapter()
        {
            Id = Id,
            Topic = Topic,
            Key = Key,
            Name = Name
        };
    }
}
```

It can be used just as the original `Chapter`. There are special conversions from and to `Chapter` which might be necessary for the view or when accessing the chapter's tracking entry in the `DbContext`.

The advantage of the above approach is that I don't have to copy every property to the view model. Furthermore, the existing validation rules hold also for the view model, which is the desired behavior in my case. Any display attributes must only be applied once and not in every view model.